# How to Mix Manual SQL Row Mapping with CrudRepository (Spring Data)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

## Context

I've seperated my application into three layers: controller, service, repository. This has been incredibly useful as I can change things on any layer without affecting the others.

Currently I'm trying to optimize some of my queries, and there are places where Entity Graphs and the generated queries are not enough for my needs. Through writing native SQL and mapping the result sets myself using my existing `@Entity`s, I believe I can produce my data quicker.

## Question

Given I have some interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

How can I extend `UserRepository` to both use `CrudRepository` methods (like `save()`, `findById()`) whilst also using my own native query methods.

I'm using hibernate as my persistance provider in a database-per-tenant environment in Java 8 with Spring Boot. I've considered the following solutions but have not been satisfied:

- JPQL - In places it's incredibly useful and saves a lot of boilerplate. But for complex queries or where I want make the most of my DB normalization, I find it difficult to use, and would rather have full control.
- NativeQuery in @Query - Requires including huge @PostConstruct annotations in the entity classes.
- Spring Data query language - Similar to above when using @Entity graphs (that were limited in depth, I discovered.).

I can't find anything in the [Spring Data Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) describing how to do this, but I'm sure I've seen such a solution described somewhere on the web.

For clarity, I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {};

public class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepository {

    public User doComplexQuery() {

        List<Result> rows = query.("select * from ... ");
        User user = new User(rows.get(0));
        return user;

    }

};

public class UserService {
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;
    public User getUser() {
         return userRepository.doComplexQuery();
    }

    public User saveUser(User user) {
         return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't really an answer that can be answered. If you describe the specific limitations you encountered we might provide help how to overcome those within the technology or with an alternative approach. But statements like "Too much magic and too limited" can't be the basis for useful answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Spring Data query language"?

Comment: @JenSchauder spring data query language is the "findbywhereorderby(...)" thing that generates the query based on the method name. And the other solutions listed were just to show I've done my research. I essentially want to mix JDBC with JPA, so surely there is a solution?

Comment: @JensSchauder I've updated with a bit more specific example of what I'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for, are [custom method implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Note, that you can inject an `EntityManager` or any other Spring Bean into the implementing class.

So the solution would look similar to this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, CustomUserRepository {};

public interface CustomUserRepository {
    User doComplexQuery();
};

public class CustomUserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public User doComplexQuery() {

        List<Result> rows = em.createNativeQuery("select * from ... ");
        User user = new User(rows.get(0));
        return user;

    }
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Just a few more questions: Given that CrudRepository is an interface, would I have to implement .save etc as well? or would Spring still provide that? And I'm aware that hibernate implements a caching mechanism, would these custom method implementations no longer utilize this?

Comment: Spring Data will still provide the implementations for the methods from CrudRepository. All caches employed by Hibernate (there are various) are encapsulated by the `EntityManager`, so you will still use them if they apply. But native queries pretty much ignore any cache AFAIK.

Comment: @JensSchauder, is it possible in java class extends interface?.

Comment: @JensSchauder thank you for your patience, and your very in depth answer!

Comment: @AngadBansode no, I messed up the code example. I think I improved it, but nobody should trust code written by myself without IDE and Tests.

Comment: @JensSchauder the Impl class has to be abstract too if I don't want to implement the .save methods I think., just testing now.

Comment: It only implements a separate interface with the custom method. I think it is already correct after my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

As for me the best and simplest choice is the combination of all options, you have described, with [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) (if I understand you correctly).

I create simple entities using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Model implements Serializable {
    //...       

    private String name;

    @OneToMany  
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Subject implements Serializable {
    //...
}
```

Then define the necessary projections, for example:

```
public interface ModelSubjects {
    List<Subject> getSubjects();
}

public interface SomeProjection {
    //...
}
```

Then extend my repo, if needed:

```
public interface ModelRepo extends JpaRepository<Model, Long> {
    @Query("select distinct m from Model m join fetch m.subjects where ...")
    List<Model> getWithJPQLQuery(...);

    @Query("select s as subjects from Model m join m.subjects s where ...")
    List<ModelSubjects> getSubjectsWithJPQLQuery(...);

    @Query(value = "some complex SQL query...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SomeProjection> getWithSQLQuery(...);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "subjects")
    List<Model> findByName(String name);    
}
```

**UPDATED**

Complex examples (see comments under the answer):

```java
@Entity
public class Forest {
    //...

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Tree> trees;
}

@Entity
public class Tree {
    //...

    @OneToMany
    private List<Branch> branches;
}

@Entity
public class Branch {
    //...
}
```

```java
public interface BranchNumberByForest {
    String getForestName();
    Long getBranchNumber();
}
```

**Native query**

```java
public interface ForestRepo extends JpaRepository<Forest, Long> {
    @Query(value = "" +
        "select " + 
        "  f.name as forestName, " + 
        "  count(b.*) as branchNumber " +
        "from " + 
        "  forests f " + 
        "  left join trees t on t.forest_id = f.id " +
        "  left join branches b on b.tree_id = t.id " +
        "group by " +
        "  f.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<BranchNumberByForest> getBranchNumbers();
}
```

**The same with JPQL**

```
public interface ForestRepo extends JpaRepository<Forest, Long> {
    @Query("" +
        "select " + 
        "  f.name as forestName, " + 
        "  count(b) as branchNumber " +
        "from " + 
        "  Forest f " + 
        "  left join f.trees t " +
        "  left join t.branches b " +
        "group by " +
        "  f.name")
    List<BranchNumberByForest> getBranchNumbers();
}
```

Comment: For your `getWithSQLQuery(..)` method in ModelRepo, how would you structure it to include children of children of children style fields? Use an example like Forest, Tree, branch, leaf.

Comment: So while I've followed through with your approach, I'd like to add that I'm using an autowired jdbctemplate with the @PersistanceContext annotation, then a result set extractor and row mapper. In case anyone wants do things reallly manually.